# How to add .current class to parent li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if someone can help me. I trying to add .current class to the active parent in my navigation.

Here is my navigation:

```
<ul id="top-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul id="about-dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have managed to get the .current class to display on the current page but when the user is on a sub page, eg. "Sub Cat 1" I want the "About" a tag to add the .current page.

Here is my Jquery:

```
 var url = window.location.pathname, 
 urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('#top-nav a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
$("li.current").parent().addClass("current");
});

                $(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.current").parent().addClass("current-parent");
});
```

If anyone can help it would be appreciated :-)

Thanks

Comment: What would be the URL when you are on "Sub Cat 1" page?

Comment: @PraveenMP would it matter? surely if you ad more menu items in the future it would automatically add the .current class rather than relying on the URL

Comment: if it is absolute URL u can search for the "about" keyword in the URL,after that using JavaScript you can add the class. either you can do it on other way on clicking of "Subcat1" link store some variable in local-storage, with the help of that you can add class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul id="top-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul id="about-dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Cat 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#top-nav li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});
$('#about-dropdown').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass('current');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).prev().removeClass('current');
});
```

CSS

```
.current{
    background: #F00;
}
```

Fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/7LzLk8aw/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.current").parents('#top-nav > li').addClass("current");
});
```

If you only want the top level item use the selector above. If you want all parents use `'#top-nav li'`